# Qual a origem dos nomes das notas musicais Dó-Ré-Mi-Fá-Sol-Lá e Si em português?

Tags: etimologia

Em português (pelo menos no Brasil), as notas músicais são conhecidas pelos nomes *Dó, Ré, Mi, Fá, Sol, Lá* e *Si*. Em inglês, p.ex. são conhecidas pelas letras de *A* até *G*, o que parece mais racional.

Qual a origem dos nomes em português das notas musicais?

In portuguese (at least in Brazil) musical notes are known as *Dó, Ré, Mi, Fá, Sol, Lá* and *Si*. In english, for instance, they are know by the letters *A* to *G*, which seems to be more rational.

What is the origin for the portuguese names of musical notes?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Enquanto isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7SmFH79huY

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A origem desses nomes para as notas, que são usados em várias línguas (incluindo francês, italiano, russo e grego), remonta à Idade Média. Consta que o italiano [Guido d'Arezzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_of_Arezzo) teria criado essa notação com fins didáticos, a partir das primeiras sílabas do canto gregoriano [*Ut queant laxis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ut_queant_laxis), um hino em Latim a São João Batista:

> **Ut** queant laxis
>   **re**sonare fibris,
>   **Mi**ra gestorum
>   **fa**muli tuorum,
>   **Sol**ve polluti
>   **la**bii reatum,
>   **S**ancte **I**ohannes.

O **ut** em algumas línguas ainda se mantém, mas em outras foi transformado em **Do** (há controvérsias sobre o motivo exato).

Comment: Quanto à última frase, recomendo uma segunda leitura. O **Do** deriva do musicólogo [Giovanni Doni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Battista_Doni).

Comment: Deixei essa parte um pouco mais vaga, considerando que já li mais de uma explicação para o Do.

Comment: Sim, é verdade que há casos complicados. Só imagino a confusão que será o facto de duas respostas apresentarem justificações diferentes.

Comment: offtopic: Eu tenho um irmão gêmeo o nome dele é Guido, aqui no Brasil todos que nos conhecem pensam ser um apelido, não sei se em Portugal pensam assim ou se o nome é mais comum.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Bem off-topic mesmo :) Guido é um nome italiano, não?

Comment: @bfavaretto Acredito que sim. Escolheram por ter as 3 primeiras letras iguais ao nome Guilherme (coisa de gêmeos :( -- individualidade é dificil kk)

Comment: Mudei um pouco minha resposta para ressaltar essa indefinição sobre a fonte exata, acho que agora fica menos confuso haha

Answer (score 15):

From the solfege notes, created by music theorist Guido of Arezzo in the 11th century. The most accepted theory is that the syllabes themselves come from the Latin hymn *Ut queant laxis*:

> **Ut** queant laxīs    **re**sonāre fībrīs
>
> **Mī**ra gestõrum    **fa**mulī tuõrum,
>
> **Sol**ve pollūtī    **la**biī reātum,
>
> Sancte Iõhannēs.

In the 1600s, **Ut** was changed to **Do**. The reason why is controversial - some sources state that it comes from ***Do***minus - Latin for "master, lord". Others (like a page on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Battista_Doni)) state that it was done by Italian musicologist Giovanni Battista Doni, who chose a syllable from his own family name. The fact is the change has stuck until today, probably because because "do" is an open syllable, easier to sing.

**Si** (allegedly based on the initials for "Sancte Iohannes" - "São João" in Portuguese) was added to complete the diatonic scale (the seven notes).

In countries with "fixed Do solfege", the solfege syllabes are used to represent the notes, instead of the letters A to G. According to Wikipedia, this includes:

> Spain, Portugal, France, Italy, Belgium, Romania, Latin American countries and in French-speaking Canada as well as countries such as Bosnia and Herzegovina, Russia, Serbia, Ukraine, Georgia, Bulgaria, Greece, Albania, Macedonia, Mongolia, Iran, Lebanon, Turkey, and Israel where non-Romance languages are spoken.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Origin